# Do not show text when using simple select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am querying a `varchar` column and I don't want to see the first characters within the row but I'm not so sure on how to go about that for a select statement. Would anyone know how? I would appreciate it.

This is the value in the table:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ftnbj{\fonttbl{\f0 \fswiss Arial;}}{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;\red0\green128\blue0 ;}{\stylesheet{\f0\fs20\cf0\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\additive\cf0\cb1 Default Paragraph Font;}}\margl1440\margr1440\margt540\margb1440\headery540\footery720\formshade\sectd\marglsxn1440\margrsxn1440\margtsxn540\margbsxn1440\headery540\footery720\sbkpage\pgncont\plain\plain\fs20\pard\plain\fs20\cf0\sscharaux1\par\fs24\b Phone Note\fs20\b0\par\par\b Initial Intake:\b0\par
```

Comment: Can you clarify. YOu dont want to see the first X characters, are there any cases where you do? You can just use `left` if you want

Comment: I dont want to see anything left of "Initial Intake:\b0\par" including that. sorry for being unclear

Comment: You should add that to your question because your question will not be looked at with the current information. DO you always want everything right of "\bo\par" what if there are multiple "bo\par"?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with a combination of [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [LEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

#### SQL Example

```
DECLARE @searchString AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @searchString = 'Initial Intake:\b0\par'

;WITH
source_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( '{\rtf1\ansi\ftnbj{\fonttbl{\f0 \fswiss Arial;}}{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;\red0\green128\blue0 ;}{\stylesheet{\f0\fs20\cf0\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\additive\cf0\cb1 Default Paragraph Font;}}\margl1440\margr1440\margt540\margb1440\headery540\footery720\formshade\sectd\marglsxn1440\margrsxn1440\margtsxn540\margbsxn1440\headery540\footery720\sbkpage\pgncont\plain\plain\fs20\pard\plain\fs20\cf0\sscharaux1\par\fs24\b Phone Note\fs20\b0\par\par\b Initial Intake:\b0\par...HERE IS THE REST OF THE STRING')
    ) tbl ([Column1]) 
)
SELECT
    [new_column] = SUBSTRING([Column1], CHARINDEX(@searchString, [Column1]) + LEN(@searchString), LEN([Column1]) - CHARINDEX(@searchString, [Column1]))
FROM    
    source_data
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1eaf48057fe4d3bdaf3fbf87c407ea2e)

#### Results

[image: screenshot]